# Is there anything like Generic templates in django like Generic views

Tags: python, django, django-models

Generic view have saved lot of code for me but i still have to write templates of every model. I have same code in all template i.e

```
<form action="/{{type}}/{{ action }}/" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" >
    {% csrf_token %}
    {% for field in form %}
        <div class="fieldWrapper">
            {{ field.errors }}
            {{ field.label_tag }}: {{ field }}
        </div>
    {% endfor %}
    <p><input type="submit" value="Submit" /></p>
    </form>
```

i.e basically i want to have all fields from the model to add or edit.

is there any work around to have generic template automatrically

Comment: Why do you need different templates? Why not just use the same template for all models? There's nothing model-specific in the code you've shown.

Comment: But generic views expects the template like app/model_form.html. othwise i have to explicitly write the template name there. so i was thinking rather than writing template name there it automatically gets that

Comment: What's the problem with explicitly writing the template name

Answer (score 2):

If you have template code that is *identical*, you can use the [include tag](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/?from=olddocs#include):

```
{% include "foo/bar.html" %}
```

And the included code can be modified with variables:

```
{% include "name_snippet.html" with person="Jane" %}
```

Even if the code is *different* for each template (I think your example is talking about forms having different fields, not sure), you can still use includes - just make two blocks:

```
{% include "startform.html with some_action="post" %}
    {{ field.errors }}
    {{ field.label_tag }}: {{ field }}
    {{ field.field2_tag }}: {{ field2 }}
{% include "endform.html %}
```

There is also [template inheritance](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/templates/language/#template-inheritance), where you can define a basic template, and have all your other templates inherit from it. Inheritance is block-based, you can override blocks in the parent template with new code in the child template. It works very well.

Answer (score 1):

Look at the [ModelForm helper app](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms/). It will make a form from any model which can then be used in a simple form template.

Answer (score 0):

In django, templates can be generic itself!!

You can use a diferent form for each model inside the same template using {{ form.attribute }}

[Here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms/) is the django oficial doc

Comment: but what should i write in `action"" attribute` of the template